# python's print causing errors in ProcessBuilder Java

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, python-3.x, processbuilder

I'm trying to use ProcessBuilder in Java to run some python code. `print` is causing errors but `print()` works fine.

The java code is:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("python", "C:/.../test.py");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(list);
Process process = pb.start();
```

It generates a file if test.py is this

```
open('C:/.../outputtest2.txt', 'a')
print(5)
```

but it doesnt't work if test.py is this

```
open('C:/.../outputtest2.txt', 'a')
print 5
```

Both work fine if I run the script from the command line. I've tried changing and even removing Python 3 from the PATH but still getting the error. I can't find any similar errors online.

Comment: It's pretty hard to know what's happening if you don't show your code. Please [edit] your question and add the relevant parts.

Comment: @Chris I've added code snippets, does that help?

Answer (score 0):

This is a python syntax error. As you know in python 3 you have to put parentheses for print function. for some reasons ( e.g. system cache) your `ProcessBuilder` use python 3 for running your python code.
This problem should solve by restarting the computer but if it doesn't work, you can run it manually with python 2.x
For example :

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("C:/python27/python.exe", "C:/.../test.py");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(list);
```